# Не работает функция замены букв на символы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет!
Необходимо написать функцию, которая бы в слове заменяла все символы на '(', если буква встречается в слове один раз и ')' , если буква встречается в слове больше одного раза.

```
def duplicate_encode(word):
    word1 = word
    for letter in list(word):
        if list(word).count(letter) > 1:
            word1.replace(letter, ')')
        else:
            word1.replace(letter, '(')
    return word1
```

Не понимаю почему, но данная функция у меня возвращает ровно тоже самое  слово, что и на входе.

Comment: `word1 = word1.replace(letter, ')')` и  `word1 = word1.replace(letter, '(')`

Comment: строки не изменяемый тип данных в питоне. новый результат нужно сохранить...

Comment: @S.Nick А вы не могли бы объяснить, пожалуйста, почему когда я пишу 
word1 = word.replace(letter, ')')  - это не работает, а если пишу word = word.replace(letter, ')')  , то работает ... по идее результат и там и там сохраняется...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `replace` возвращает новую строку, а не изменяет старую.

```
def duplicate_encode(word):
    word1 = word
    for letter in list(word):
        if list(word).count(letter) > 1:
            word1 = word1.replace(letter, ')')
        else:
            word1 = word1.replace(letter, '(')
    return word1

word = "aaabcddf"

print(word)
print(duplicate_encode(word))
```

Comment: К `list` приводить не обязательно. И цикл лучше сделать `for letter in set(word):`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов да, можно и ещё лучше написать, но я только исправил основную ошибку в коде автора